# Simplified error handling when reading from stdin and parsing to a type

Tags: parsing, error-handling, rust

I've recently started learning Rust, and I've managed to whip up this function, which reads and parses a thing from `stdin`. I don't like it though, and I feel it could be further simplified. What do you think?

```
fn read_thing<T: str::FromStr>() -> Result<T, &'static str> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(_)  => match buffer.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n)  => Ok(n),
            Err(_) => Err("Failed parsing input.")
        },
        Err(_) => Err("Failed reading from stdin."),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few possibilities. They all rely on the fact that `Result` can be mapped over, both in the success and failure cases.

Additionally, I personally *detest* having trait bounds on generics inside the generic declaration. I almost always move them to a `where` clause for readability.

---

```
fn read_thing<T>() -> Result<T, &'static str>
    where T: str::FromStr
{
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    try!(io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).map_err(|_| "Failed reading from stdin."));
    buffer.trim().parse().map_err(|_| "Failed parsing input.")
```

This is the most direct modification to your existing code. It transforms the errors into the desired strings and uses the `try!` macro to return immediately on the first error.

---

```
use std::io::BufRead;

fn read_thing<T>() -> Result<T, &'static str>
    where T: str::FromStr
{
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let v = stdin.lock().lines().next()
        .ok_or("No data to read")
        .and_then(|s| s.map_err(|_| "Failed reading from stdin"))
        .and_then(|s| s.trim().parse().map_err(|_| "Failed parsing input"));
    v
}
```

This was an attempt to chain it all together. It almost works nicely, but introduces a new error condition - what if stdin is fine, there's just nothing to read? Add to that the lifetime shenanigans that involve locking the standard in, and this isn't the nicest either.

---

```
fn one_line_from_stdin() -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).map(|_| buffer)
}

fn read_thing2<T>() -> Result<T, &'static str>
    where T: str::FromStr
{
    one_line_from_stdin()
        .map_err(|_| "Failed reading from stdin")
        .and_then(|s| s.trim().parse().map_err(|_| "Failed parsing input"))
}
```

Continuing on a quest to chain it together, I extracted a method that just returns a single string. It's probably not very efficient, but reads OK.

---

```
fn read_thing2<T>() -> Result<T, &'static str>
    where T: str::FromStr
{
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).map(|_| buffer)
        .map_err(|_| "Failed reading from stdin")
        .and_then(|s| s.trim().parse().map_err(|_| "Failed parsing input"))
```

Same idea as the previous code, this just inlines the input method.

---

```
use std::error::Error;

fn read_thing<T>() -> Result<T, Box<Error>>
    where T: str::FromStr,
          T::Err: Error + 'static,
{
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    try!(io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer));
    let v = try!(buffer.trim().parse());
    Ok(v)
}
```

This is what I'd probably write to start with. I find the messages from most errors to be fairly readable and understandable, but I'm not showing them to an end user most of the time. I'd just use a little elegance baked into the `try!` macro and the `From` implementation of `Box<Error>` to pass back the original errors, abstracted out to the generic concept of an error. More information can be found in [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#error-handling-with-boxerror).

If I cared more about custom messages or efficiency, I'd upgrade to a [custom error type](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#error-handling-with-a-custom-type). I've also recently discovered the [quick_error crate](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error) which provides a macro to make custom types easier, but haven't had a chance to try it out yet.